# Gigabyte GA-Z68AP-D3 not booting

Tags: boot, motherboard

I recently purchased the following PC components: *Gigabyte XKT-1155 Z68AP-D3*, along with *Intel 3rd Generation Core i5-3570K CPU*, *Kingston 8GB 1333MHz DDR3 Non-ECC* and *Asus nVIDIA GeForce 210 Graphics Card (512MB, DDR3, PCI Express 2.0, HDMI).*

I did setup the computer and I think I did it right. Basically everything inside starts loading ( the LEDs start working the fans too ), but I don't see anything on my screen, nor any of the peripherals are working ( I tried both USB and PS2 keyboards ). Also the computer is not making any alert sounds ( beep ).
Does anyone have a clue of what the problem might be, or any sort of advice?

( also, this is a working computer, so that's why I've picked that specific video card :) )

**Edit**: After looking through the interwebs, I only found one relevant topic on this question, which is [here](http://goo.gl/d7k4B), but the problem I'm having is that I'm not allowed to post on that forum, even though I registered and activated my account.

**Edit 2**:
Okay!

I narrowed down the issue. Problem was that I had an 'Ivy bridge' processor which is not supported by the motherboard unless you update the BIOS. Which pretty much sucks, as I'm supposed to order another processor, update the BIOS version and start using the i5.

Solution? I've ordered another motherboard, Asus P8Z77-V LX it's called :)

Comment: Did you try plugging the monitor into the onboard HDMI slot?

Comment: @Dennis - no, as I don't have a HDMI cable. But as I mentioned above the keyboard is not working either ( no led coming on ) and I tried several of them...

Comment: @Seb please post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay!

I narrowed down the issue. Problem was that I had an 'Ivy bridge' processor which is not supported by the motherboard unless you update the BIOS. Which pretty much sucks, as I'm supposed to order another processor, update the BIOS version and start using the i5.

Solution? I've ordered another motherboard, Asus P8Z77-V LX it's called :)

Answer (score 1):

May be the ram has not been inserted properly. Remove ram, clean it and insert it properly.Is cpu fan working properly?

Comment: I tried removing the RAM completely and the computer goes into a 'restart loop' ( keeps restarting ). The CPU fan is working properly ( as long as I have RAM inside of it ), everything else is clean and tidy...

Comment: can you access bios?

Comment: where have you connected the monitor cable to graphics card or motherboard?]\

Comment: no mate, that's the problem. Nothing works aside from the fans and the leds on the motherboard. No display, no keyboard ( it doesn't light up the leds ).

Comment: only graphics card, as I don't have an HDMI cable and the motherboards only output is the HDMI port.

Comment: When ram is inserted is your system restarting as you stated above? If yes then the heat sink is not fixed properly. Otherwise   your system's primary video will be onboard and you may have to change it from bios.Its just a guess but try it....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3954/discussion-between-seb-and-gladiator2345)